# How to get floating divs to register as content in their parent?

Tags: css

Some more detail: I've got two divs, one `float:left`, the other `float:right`, and the parent is `clear:both` so that I can order the container parents downwards on the page. Specific CSS is here:

```
#content {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 750px;
    margin-top:50px;
    position:relative;
}
.container-div {
    padding-top:7px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#b0c4de;
}
.left-side {
    float:left;
}
.right-side
    float:right;
}
```

The problem is that the `background-color` of the parent only covers a tiny bit on the top of the container, and chrome inspector shows that the content is apparently only that portion. What gives? How do I make the div see the float'ed divs as content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split Div Into 2 Columns Using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964297/split-div-into-2-columns-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: auto` on the parent

Comment: `overflow: hidden` will also work in this case (may or may not be appropriate. I you want `clear: both` to work then this needs to be applied to an element inside the parent, but below the floated elements. Whoever downvoted - learn your CSS. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your DOM structure more or less look like this

```
<div class="container-div">
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="right-side"></div>
</div>
```

The parent div with class container have a width of 100%.
Now you are trying to float two child div's within the parent div without giving them any width, by default the child div's will take 100% width.
So you have to define the child div's width atmost 50% then only your float will be effective.

Now try the following codes

```
.clear{clear:both}

.container-div {
    padding-top:7px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#b0c4de;
}
.left-side {
    float:left;
    width=50%;
}
.right-side
    float:right;
    width=50%;
}
```

And your DOM should look like this

```
<div class="container-div">
        <div class="left-side">your left divs content</div>
        <div class="right-side">your right divs content</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Now you will see that everything is in correct place and chrome inspector will show it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The parent `.container-div` should be set to `display: inline-block;` in order to take in the full height of it's children.