# Table with fused rows

Tags: html, html-table

I need the following type of table in html

[image]

i.e., with fused rows in the second column (one entity). Basically, there would be text in the four non-fused cells and an image in the fused ones. How can I do this? If there is a way wherein I can avoid the use of tables, that would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use rowspan="4" attribute in the second TD of the first row. e.g.

```
   <table>
       <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td rowspan="4"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
```

This specifies that the second cell in the first row spans over 4 rows. Notice that in the 2nd to 4th rows there is no need to specify a second column as that is already specified in the first row.

However: if you are using this just for layout then I would avoid the table altogether and use some divs and CSS to achieve the same result.

```
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="left">
             <div></div>
             <div></div>
             <div></div>
             <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
           <!-- image here -->
        </div>
        <br style="clear:both;"/>
    </div>
```

And CSS:

```
    .left{
       float:left;

     }
    .right{
       float:left
     }
```

You can find some good advice on this layout in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3442769/27439).

Or with Bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">Your Image Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it should be `rowspan`. I mean `rowspan` works, `colspan` doesn't in my case. Secondly, can I do anything better than using tables?

Comment: Thanks @Ranveer...that's absolutely right. I had things crooked in my head.

Comment: Ah! Great idea! `float` totally ought to work. The problem is my webpage is responsive (I'm using bootstrap 3.0). Won't it screw up?

Comment: Ah Bootstrap..that makes a big difference.  Bootstrap has all the things you need to make this layout and to make it fluid.

Comment: I can't use `col-xx-#` since this layout is already inside one.

Comment: You are allowed to nest these grids. Just wrap it in a another row and it should work. If you are already familiar with doing it in bootstrap then give it a try.

Comment: That worked well! So basically this question had nothing to do with my problem! Thanks for your help!