# Splitting divs into 2 columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a code like this:

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title1</h3>
    <p>article1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title2</h3>
    <p>article2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title3</h3>
    <p>article3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title4</h3>
    <p>article4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to transform this 1 lined column into 2 columns like this:

[image: example image]

I already tried to use this code, but is there any different way to split the div?

```css
.article-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.article {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.article:after {
  content: "";
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title1</h3>
    <p>article1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title2</h3>
    <p>article2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title3</h3>
    <p>article3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title4</h3>
    <p>article4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's different from this other question [Split Div Into 2 Columns Using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964297/split-div-into-2-columns-using-css), the "article" arrangement from this question is different. Anyone got the idea?

Comment: what is  wrong with flex ?

Comment: I would say bootstrap or flex would be a useful thing to pick up, unless this is for homework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Div Into 2 Columns Using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964297/split-div-into-2-columns-using-css)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nothing wrong with flexbox for this layout.

There's no need to use a pseudo-element.

```css
.article-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.article {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title1</h3>
    <p>article1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title2</h3>
    <p>article2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title3</h3>
    <p>article3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title4</h3>
    <p>article4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using float/clear:

```css
.article {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.article:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title1</h3>
    <p>article1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title2</h3>
    <p>article2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title3</h3>
    <p>article3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title4</h3>
    <p>article4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try using CSS3 Columns. But in this case, it looks a bit different in the information flow.

```css
.article-container {
  -webkit-columns: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-columns: 2; /* Firefox */
  columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title1</h3>
    <p>article1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title2</h3>
    <p>article2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title3</h3>
    <p>article3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title4</h3>
    <p>article4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite simple. You just need to set `.article` to `display: inline-block;`, and seporate the second one from the first one with a `<br>`, and perhaps `width: 49%;` on the `.article` to get the effect of a proper column

```css
.article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title1</h3>
    <p>article1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title2</h3>
    <p>article2</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title3</h3>
    <p>article3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h3>title4</h3>
    <p>article4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```